# a simple regexp validator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

How do a I create a validator, which has these simple rules. An expression is valid if

it must start with a letter
it must end with a letter
it can contain a dash (minus sign), but not at start or end of the expression

Comment: You should specify how the part between start and end may look like.

Comment: Right... in other words, is the whole thing supposed to be letters other than the possibility of having a dash in the middle?

Comment: This is far too vague.  Can there be anything at all between the dashes and letters as long as it starts and ends with a letter?  

Or are the starting and ending letter and possible dash the only things there can be?  That would limit the string to either 2 or 3 characters in length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/^[A-Za-z]+(-?[A-Za-z]+)?$/
```

this seems like what you want.

^ = match the start position
^[A-Za-z]+ = start position is followed by any at least one or more letters.
-? = is there zero or one hyphens (use "*" if there can be multiple hyphens in a row).
[A-Za-z]+ = hyphen is followed by one or more letters
(-?[A-Za-z]+)? = for the case that there is a single letter.
$= match the end position in the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
^[a-zA-Z]+-?[a-zA-Z]+$
```

E.g.

```
def validate(whatever)
  reg = /^[a-zA-Z]+-?[a-zA-Z]+$/
return (reg.match(whatever)) ? true : false;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression matches sequences, that consist of one or more words of letters, that are concatenated by dashes.

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(?:-[a-zA-Z]+)*$
```

Answer (score 0):

xmammoth pretty much got it, with one minor problem.  My solution is:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+\-?[a-zA-Z]+$
```

Note that the original question states, it **can** contain a dash.  The question mark is needed after the dash to make sure that it is optional in the regex.

Comment: But the backslash before the dash is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z]$
```

In other words: letter, anything, letter.

Might also want:

```
^[A-Za-z](.*[A-Za-z])?$
```

so that a single letter is also matched.

Answer (score 0):

What I meant, to be able to create tags. For example: "Wild-things" or "something-wild" or "into-the-wild" or "in-wilderness" "my-wild-world" etc...

Comment: You can edit your post.  Open up the post and click on "edit" below and to the left of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

```
[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z]
```

According to your rules that will work. It will match anything that:

- starts with a letter
- ends with a letter
- can contain a dash (among everything else) in between.